# shell script array length

Tags: arrays, shell

I assume arguments to my shell scripts willbe `./x.sh subject N file1 file2 fileN`
So I am splicing `argv` from 3 till end `candidates=${@:3}`

now I want to check whether length of candidates is same as given `N` I am trying with `echo $((${#candidates[@]}))` which is always returning `1`.

I can do `echo "$#-2" | bc` but, I shouldn't I be able to get array size ?

I can use `bc` to do integer comparison. but I've to know the size of `candidates array which I am not getting properly.

Comment: What shell?  Many shells don't even support arrays!

Comment: Yes, but what shell?  `${@:3}` is a syntax error in many shells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are assigning `candidates` is not making an array.  To make it an array, do:

```
candidates=(${@:3})
```

In bash, you can get the number of elements in the array with `${#candidates[*]}`.  To check if that is equal to `$2`, just do:

```
[[ ${#candidates[*]} == "$2" ]]
```

Comment: `candidates=${@:3}
 echo ${#candidates[*]}` is returning 1

Comment: `candidates` is not an array!

Comment: Thanks the parenthesis fixed it. one more question here I am slicing 3 to end. but how can I slice 3 to end-1 th element ?

Comment: You could do: `candidates=(${@:3:$(($#-3))})`

Comment: `candidates=(${@:3:n})` always gets first element only doesn't matter whatever I put in place of n

Comment: @Dipro.  In an array, `$candidates` is a synonym for `${candidates[0]}`, so perhaps you are only displaying the first entry? `(${@:3:2})` should give put two elements in the array.